# (Discord.py) message bot through dm, then sending to a channel

Tags: discord.py

I’m trying to make a code that you can dm the bot for help, suggestions, or whatever and it will send the message in a channel. Once you get the message you can do .dm (user) (message) and then the bot will then dm the user back. I’m having some issues I’m pretty new to coding and I think my format is outdated. If someone could help that would be awesome.

```
@vini.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = vini.get_channel('633053538334932992')
    if message.guild is None and message.author != vini.user:
      await channel.send(message.content)
    await vini.process_commands(message)

@vini.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.is_owner() 
async def dm(ctx):
  memberID = "ID OF RECIPIENT"
  person = await vini.get_user_info(memberID)
  await ctx.send(“WHAT TO SAY", delete_after=2)
```

Error:

```
File "main.py", line 133, in on_message
    await channel.send(message.content)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

If someone could help it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that `channel = vini.get_channel('633053538334932992')` is affecting the value `None` to your `channel` variable, are you sure that the channel ID is correct?

Comment: You should also check if your bot have access to the specified channel, and other things [stated here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2282#issuecomment-513530155)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' - Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343781/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-send-discord-bot)

Comment: I see what I did wrong, I’m doing a string it needs to be an int. Thanks for help!