# Discord content

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, discord.py

```
import discord
import asyncio 
import asyncpg
from discord.ext import commands

async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel('654057661142269964')
    await channel.send('verify')
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Test")
    return

 client.run(Token)
```

That is the code I am using with Python 3.7, but the problem is I get no response on Discord, although I get the error:

```
line 13, in on_message
    await channel.send('verify')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' - Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343781/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-send-discord-bot)

Comment: Sadly no. As I'm just trying to get it to monitor the input for just one channel not all channels and every fix on the link you suggested did not work.

Comment: `client.get_channel` requires `int` type to work. Try `channel = client.get_channel(654057661142269964)`

Comment: I didn't try that but i Did try    `channel = client.get_channel(int('654057661142269964'))`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're mixing syntax from different versions of discord.py. `Client.send_message` is from discord.py v0.16, an outdated version that isn't supported anymore. You should look into [migrating to v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html).
Note, IDs are in fact strings in that version. They've only been integers in the latest versions since the v1 update.

Regardless, as [the documentation for`Client.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) says, it returns `None` if the channel is not found. You'll want to add a check afterwards to see if the channel was found or not before using it.